# How to embed Vuetify app in page with height fitting the content and not affecteding css global scope - v-app vs v-layout

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I want to have a vuetify app I want to embed in a webpage with other stuff. Thus I have essentially two requirements:

- cover only has much height as needed for the content
- do not affect css scope outside of the vuetify application

To what I read v-app is used by vuetify internally to scope css classes and thus I guess the way to achieve requirement number 2. However v-app always covers full height even if I set `:full-height="false"` (As you can see in my sample: https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlkc9OwzAMxl/F5DKQlgaxWxkIbrwBB8qha90tkH9K3KFp6rvjtENMG4dJXCrFn/37Prtve/EcQrHtUZRiSWiDqQkfKwew3Mo6BEi0M/hQiVXdfK6j710rG298LCO29xvU6w2VnSYuOkJHlYCy642Rk8SDXW0SVmJkAkxfAMJEsN/btB6GX2WpRlPuXaqjMPxMTdSBICH1WdY2+MgAiNjBAF30Fma8xSw3cxSGMxoesn49e0FjPLz6aNqr2U2GTzgGibmYWNLWofhI3vEh9jlLdRBSJUoYK7nGHvldiQ1RSKVSTet4rEWjt7FwSMoFq564TcXekbYoW2+fFsWiuJUrpLpYqFYnOlYLTFauov9KGJlVifmRG+lud4HjoZON7oq7yeFQkqZepWxxhlbst8UoI7oWI8ZLFzsZ+2O5k46zBXMI/u0DX99o95lODt+k8ehvP1n/tfkIy6T3bDjMxXFcDjDOifdvCHgIIQ==)

Thus I wonder how to best bring these two together. Any ideas

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `min-height` from `.v-application__wrap`:

```css
  .v-application .v-application__wrap{
    min-height: unset;
  }
```

(see [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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))

Note however that Vuetify is notorious for not scoping styles (just place a button outside `v-app`, see how it looks). You can disable some of it, like [css reset](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/css-reset/) with [SASS variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/), but I'd be surprised if you get it to not bleed over at all.

Comment: Yeah the global scope pollution is really a pain - and indeed the button is always my test sample. You dont' possibly know if there are plans to fix that?

Comment: Good question, I have no idea. But I haven't actually tested v3 without css reset, maybe the issue is fixed already and I am just spouting old news. Might be you are in luck. Hope it works out!